# WP Choose another post type as parent

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I want to create a nice readable permalink structure for my 2 custom post types. First CPT "Countries", The second CPT "Regions".

Here is my code to insert region

```
// region options
$region_item = array(
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
    'post_author' => $user->ID,
    'post_title' => $region_name,
    'post_content' => $region_content,
    'post_status' => $post_status,
    'post_type' => 'region'
);

// insert region
$region_item_id = wp_insert_post($region_item);
```

So the URL will be : http://www.ex.com/USA/Nevada But when I call this URL wordpress displays a not-found-page, so my question is how can i fix this URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings->permalinks and refresh the page. This flushes the rewrite rules for you.

Also:
This is an argument for the register_post_type(array()to rename that default slug (your.com/slug/post-name) Might be a good option to play around with.

```
    //'rewrite' => false, /* you can specify its url slug */
    'rewrite'   => array( 
        'slug' => 'USA', //a slug used to identify the post type in URLs.
        'with_front' => false,
        'feed'=> true,  
        'pages'=> true 
        ),
```

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain well, I'm using 'More Types' plugin to create other types in WP.

first problem is when i go to the one of the Countries i see in the url index.php?Countries=USA i need it to be like http://www.ex.com/USA/

my second problem i need to make the regions to be child to Countries like this http://www.ex.com/USA/Nevada

Comment: Have you specified a permalink structure within Settings->permalinks? You want /%postname%/ in the "custom" field. Also Try this link [link]http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-more-types-permalinks-fix

Comment: didn't fix my problem /?countries=/USA

Comment: Then that plugin is bunk. My answers are all correct. Did you notice this on the plugin page?!
Compatible up to: 3.1.4
Last Updated: 2011-9-3
If you would like a fast crash course in creating CPT's with code I can help. I've learned to make it super easy.

Comment: I'm trying now to create one if i faced any problem i will let you know, thank you for your help

Comment: I fixed my first issue put the second one i can't handle it how can i set parent post to post of different type ?
ex : USA/Nevada